# How to fetch session values inside Business Logic Layer?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Good day. I have to pass the session value to a business logic layer, I can pass it to the function from presentation layer but how can I access it directly in my business logic layer ? Also is it a good approach to pass it directly to business logic layer like

```
GetMyRecords(Count,Session["userID"].toString()); ?
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per John's reply above, you ideally do not want to access any UI elements in your business layer.
You should pass the session values from your presentation layer to the business layer so that the business layer is only aware of the values - not where they are coming from.

As regards your second point about how to pass the values from presentation layer
I would suggest you should atleast wrap Session["userID"].toString()) as a property in your presentation layer.
Because its a property, you can add checking / validation logic if needed.

Also, i find it cleaner to have a wrapper SessionWrapper class and use that in the application for accessing the session values.  The advantage of this is that if your Session Persistence changes, its usually a one place change. Of course, this is not necessary as the .NET Session Providers can be plugged in via configuration even if you create your own provider.

Comment: Thank you In Sane. I made a repository class outside the Business Logic layer which returns session variables. Thumbs up !

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend to not access `Session` from within the business logic layer. The intention of having separate layers is that they serve different purposes. For example the business logic layer should not - generally speaking - contain any reference to the user interface technology, e.g. `Session` in this case.

The translation from the presentation layer (aka UI Layer) to what the business layer expects should be done in the presentation layer. Who knows? Maybe next week your boss asks you to move the business logic off that web server and onto an application server and use WCF based communication between them.

Clear separation keeps more (all?) of the paths open for tomorrow even if you don't know how tomorrow will look like.

Comment: Thank you John. You are spot on about the layer separation. How can I access it via a repository class ?

Comment: I think it's probably more about the information you'd like to make available from the `Session`. For example if your session has a customerID you may just extract it in the presentation layer, then pass it as a parameter to the business logic layer. As to the repository class: I typically use it only as an interface to the data access layer from within the business logic layer. In that scenario the repository class would be two layers apart from the presentation layer.